# TSpeedButton with TabOrder property

Tags: delphi, button, tab-ordering

in my Panel, i have  " `TSpeedButton`. There are no Tab Order property to order this 3 speed button.

How can organize speed button on my panel?

Comment: What do you mean by "organize"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TSpeedButton` derives from `TGraphicControl` and so does not accept input focus. This is why there is no `TabOrder` property.

If you wish your buttons to be able to receive input focus then you need to use a different button class. For example, `TButton` or `TBitBtn`.